# Not able to read file name

Tags: java, file

This file name is in chinese character I need to just read the file name and display it in my console, for this I am using  `if(fileName.startsWith("=?iso-8859-1"))`
but its not coming inside if statement.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
            clsEmail objEmail = new clsEmail();
            File f = new File("P://1008/Work In Progress/Vijay Bheemanaik/pdf/Cisco-S11-    POA1800005815-Inv04736851-100919重做没有.pdf");
           String fileName = f.getName();
           if (fileName != null)
              {
                if(fileName.startsWith("=?iso-8859-1"))
                {

                       System.out.println("File name 2= "+fileName);

                }

              }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: print the file name before   "if(fileName.startsWith("=?iso-8859-1"))" to see if it starts like condition of yours?

Comment: Why do you think the file name starts with "=?iso-8859-1" ? You have create a File object already with an absolut path.

Comment: You could do the opposite: check if the name can be encoded in ASCII using this: `Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder().canEncode(fileName)`.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you're trying to do ? Your question is not clear at all...

Answer (score 1):

```
File f = new File("P://1008/Work In Progress/Vijay Bheemanaik/pdf/Cisco-S11-    POA1800005815-Inv04736851-100919重做没有.pdf");
String fileName = f.getName();
if(fileName.startsWith("=?iso-8859-1"))
```

Your filename starts with `Cisco-S11`… and not `=?iso`….

Being able to pass encoding to a String like that would be new to me.